# what is the proper way to use "include makefile"?

Tags: linux, unix, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Common GNU makefile directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322936/common-gnu-makefile-directory-path)

After reading [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) I decided to use "include makefile" to my next project. I got a main Makefile that include two sub-makefiles that are in diffrent dirs. the problem is that the paths that inside the sub-makefile is relative to his dir so when I include it from the main Makefile he can't find the files. is there a way to solve this problem without changing the paths?

Comment: You could also consider using other builders, like [omake]: http://omake.metaprl.org/

Comment: similar to: [common-gnu-makefile-directory-path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322936/common-gnu-makefile-directory-path). that link should answer your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7321954/412080

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to change the paths? There are other ways, but I don't think there are *better* ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the article is right about recursive make and DAG tree, I read the article about half a year ago and tried to use the approach described in it and found the "classic" approach to recursive make much more convenient. Consider this:

```
big_project
|--Makefile
|
|--sub_project_1
|  |--...
|  |--Makefile
|
|--sub_project_2
   |--...
   |--Makefile
```

It's wonderful when you're running make from `big_project` project directory, but well, if you do things as it's recommended in the article, there would be no Makefiles in `sub_project_x` directories, thus you won't be able to treat each sub-project separately.