# How to launch a make from a sub dir

Tags: makefile, subdirectory

I have one top level `Makefile`. The project has several subdirectories of various depths.

How can I launch `make` from any subdirectory, so it uses the top level Makefile, just like `git` finds automatically its top-level `.git` directory ?

Structure :

```
/
/a/
/b/c
/Makefile
/Readme
```

Scenario :

```
/$ make
... Works ...
/b$ make
... Cannot find makefile
```

I'd like the 2nd scenario to do the same as the first one.

Hint, it would ideally serve as `:make` rule in `vi`, but shouldn't be vi-specific

Update: the / is not the root dir, only the root of the project, the real intent is to mimic git

Comment: How about `alias make="make -f /Makefile"`?

Comment: The trick is mimic git

Comment: @beta the / is not the root dir, only the root of the project, sorry

Comment: So `alias make="make -f /path/to/root/of/project/Makefile"`.

Comment: ... And I do not want to babysit the alias each time I change project

Comment: ... But I think I get the idea. thx !

Comment: might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322936/common-gnu-makefile-directory-path

Comment: You should have mentioned multiple projects in the question. How about a script that crawls up the tree until it finds a `makefile`?

Comment: @beta yup, that's what I did. If you write such a sample script as an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash  

HERE=$PWD

while ! [ -f Makefile ] && [ $PWD != "/" ]
do
 cd ..
done

MFILE=$PWD/Makefile

cd $HERE
make -f $MFILE
```

Comment: Beware of the infinite loop if Makefile is not found. Accepting it, since you made the first comments that lead to it.

Comment: @SteveSchnepp: Funny, I thought of that and then forgot to put it in. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Hint by Beta would work.
create a alias

```
alias make=`sh /home/makecrawl.sh`
```

where `makecrawl.sh` would look like

```
#! /bin/bash
while ! [ -f makefile ] &&  [$PWD != "/" ]
do
cd ..
done
make
```

Comment: @steve schnepp: thanks for the warning..
while ! [ -f Makefile ] && [ $PWD != "/" ] would work