# How to get current relative directory of your Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, working-directory

I have a several Makefiles in app specific directories like this:

```
/project1/apps/app_typeA/Makefile
/project1/apps/app_typeB/Makefile
/project1/apps/app_typeC/Makefile
```

Each Makefile includes a .inc file in this path one level up:

```
/project1/apps/app_rules.inc
```

Inside app_rules.inc I'm setting the destination of where I want the binaries to be placed when built. I want all binaries to be in their respective `app_type` path:

```
/project1/bin/app_typeA/
```

**I tried using `$(CURDIR)`**, like this:

```
OUTPUT_PATH = /project1/bin/$(CURDIR)
```

but instead I got the binaries buried in the entire path name like this: **(notice the redundancy)**

```
/project1/bin/projects/users/bob/project1/apps/app_typeA
```

What can I do to get the "current directory" of execution so that I can know just the **`app_typeX`** in order to put the binaries in their respective types folder?

Answer (score 419, accepted):

## The shell function.

You can use [`shell`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) function: `current_dir = $(shell pwd)`.
Or `shell` in combination with [`notdir`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html), if you need not absolute path:
`current_dir = $(notdir $(shell pwd))`.

## Update.

Given solution only works when you are running `make` from the Makefile's current directory.
As @Flimm noted:

> Note that this returns the current working directory, not the parent directory of the Makefile. 
> For example, if you run `cd /; make -f /home/username/project/Makefile`, the `current_dir` variable will be `/`, not `/home/username/project/`.

Code below will work for Makefiles invoked from any directory:

```
mkfile_path := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
current_dir := $(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(mkfile_path))))
```

Comment: That does not work. It is the same problem. pwd prints the full path name, I just want the name of the actual current folder I'm in.

Comment: @unexpected62 What about `notdir`?

Comment: Thanks. I am a make noob. So what's going on here exactly? notdir is removing everything _through_ the last slash in the output of pwd? I saw https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html

Comment: Yep, `notdir` does just that.

Comment: It needs to have the value expanded immediately so the := operator should be used. As in mkfile_path := and current_dir = (otherwise the right side values could be evaluated later when the MAKEFILE_LIST has changed after other Makefiles were included

Comment: Note that a similar issue occurs is you use -C to specify the directory in which to make. The $PWD will be the directory you ran gmake from.

Comment: sad thing is that this doesn't work for AutoMake (Makefile.am files) :(

Comment: I know this is an old question but I just ran into and thought this could be useful. This also will not work when there is a space in the relative path of the makefile. Specifically, `$(lastword "$(MAKEFILE_LIST)")` of a makefile at path `"Sub Directory/Makefile"` will give you `"Directory/Makefile"`. I dont think there is any way around this since `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)` with two makefiles gives you a single string `"Makefile One Makefile Two`, which cannot handle spaces

Comment: @mrosales I am having this same problem. You could get it from shell  with `${PWD##*/} `, but `$(shell ${PWD##*/} )` complains, that `*** unterminated call to function `shell': missing `)'.`

Comment: See my variant answer for gnu make version 3.80, which doesn't have lastword, realpath or abspath.

Comment: these don't seem to work if there is a space in the path

Comment: I have created an answer that demonstrates this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49740268/117471

Comment: The updated methods doesn't work if there are spaces in the path to the Makefile. It's the `dir` that fails if there are spaces. That should be mentioned in the answer along with any possible workarounds.

Comment: That `current_dir` doesn't work for me.  `$(PWD)` does and it's much simpler.

Comment: @mrosales @fbence GNU make, in general, doesn't really handle paths that have spaces in them. Something as simple as `SRCS` variable with all your source file names in it no longer works if a single file has a space in its name.

Comment: `current_dir` is not what I expected. `mkfile_dir := $(dir $(mkfile_path))` is what I expected: full path to the makefile directory.

Comment: `"solution only works when you are running make from the Makefile's current directory"` is a mild way to say "not really working". I would put the latest piece at the top of the answer.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai except that answer is abysmally wrong... any answer of PWD is wrong.  And if you are going to be that incorrect use the built in CURDIR instead.

Comment: does not work - if you're including other files from `Makefile` - this will return the path of the last included file!

Comment: @carbolmyer: I use included makefiles extensively.  I *think* that by using $(firstword...) instead of $(lastword...), this can be made to work, assuming the makefile you want is the first one you read.  But I won't claim that this works in every situation.  In particular, it would not work to find the directory for an intermediate 'include'd makefile.  So the statement in my case is
`current_dir=$(dir $(abspath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))`
It is a little surprising that make doesn't have a built-in variable for the full path of the current makefile.

Comment: Changing `mkfile_path` to `mkfile_path := $(lastword $(abspath $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))` works for me when the directory path contains spaces

Answer (score 200):

As taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322936/common-gnu-makefile-directory-path);

```
ROOT_DIR:=$(shell dirname $(realpath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
```

Shows up as;

```
$ cd /home/user/

$ make -f test/Makefile 
/home/user/test

$ cd test; make Makefile 
/home/user/test
```

Comment: IMHO it would better to use internal make-function `dir` instead of `shell dirname` though it gets pathname with trailing `/` character.

Comment: @SergeRoussak Could you perhaps write a seperate answer explaining why? I don't know enough about make to give an informed opinion.

Comment: because of reduction of dependancies on external tools. Ie what if there will alias of dirname command at some system?..

Comment: This almost worked for me, but DIR had a leading whitespace, so a minor change made work perfectly: `DIR:=$(strip $(shell dirname $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))))`

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenLorenz, I've edited the answer to reflect this

Comment: To reference the *current* makefile, the use of `$MAKEFILE_LIST` must precede any `include` operations ([docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-makefiles_002c-and-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-variable)).

Comment: Should use quotes -- at least around the argument to `dirname` -- in case there are spaces in the path.

Comment: The `:=` (vs plain `=`) is important if you have any `include` statements, since otherwise the included makefiles will come after the current makefile.

Comment: @SergeRoussak: `dirname` (and its cousin `basename`) are POSIX. I agree, "what if your system does not have `dirname`?" is a valid question, but so is "what if your system does not have `make`?" :-) Also, AFAIK, `$(realpath )` is a relatively recent, and GNU-make specific. So here is *more* dependency on tools for ya. But your `$(dir )` suggestion is a good one!

Comment: Note that you need to enforce immediate variable expansion using the `:=` operator. Otherwise, you get funky behavior.

Comment: This answer is susceptible to path splitting.   If the path of the Makefile has a space in it then the ROOT_DIR will not contain the correct path.  To resolve this the output of realpath must be surrounded by double quotes such as follows: `ROOT_DIR:=$(shell dirname "$(realpath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))")`

Comment: @user7343148 Feel free to submit an amendment, thanks

Answer (score 76):

If you are using GNU make, $(CURDIR) is actually a built-in variable.  It is the <strike>location where the Makefile resides</strike> *the current working directory, which is probably where the Makefile is, but not always*.

```
OUTPUT_PATH = /project1/bin/$(notdir $(CURDIR))
```

See Appendix A Quick Reference in http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: From the GNU Make manual (page 51): " when GNU make starts (after it has processed any -C options) it sets the variable CURDIR to the pathname of the current working directory." Not the location of where the Makefile is located - although, they might be the same.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer is not technically correct, as noted by Simon Peverett in the previous comment.

Comment: @SimonPeverett: The expression in brackets means the the "current working directory AFTER -C opts applied". Namely $(CURDIR) gives the exactly the same results for "make -C xxx" and "cd xxx; make". Also it removes the trailing `/`. I tried tied with `gmake` v3.81. But You are right if `make` is called as `make -f xxx/Makefile`.

Comment: `CURDIR` works for me where `PWD` did not.  I did `mkdir -p a/s/d` then in each folder had a makefile which printed `PWD` and `CURDIR` before `+$(MAKE) <subdir>`.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  No need to reinvent the wheel.  Make does it for you ootb.

Answer (score 35):

```
THIS_DIR := $(dir $(abspath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
```

Comment: ... unless you have spaces in any paths.

Comment: ... unless you have included some other makefile in previous line

Comment: @robal Yep. That is what I just encountered. This works _great_ if you only have two Makefiles (the main one plus an included one).

Comment: This works well for me (haven't tested spaces in dirs, but I don't expect to encounter this). The main issue I had with this code is that `$(dir)` retains the last path separator. Adding `$(realpath)` before it solves that problem.

Comment: To make more details to what @robal wrote, you should use `lastword` and not `firstword`, while for simple Makefile this "array" is of size one so choosing the first element is equivalent to choosing the last element, but in order to have the path of the directory where this line is written you would like to pick the last name from that space delimited list.

Answer (score 27):

### The simple, correct, modern way:

*For GNU make >= 3.81, which was introduced in 2006*

```
ROOT_DIR := $(dir $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
```

1. `MAKEFILE_LIST` changes as include files come in and out of scope. The last item is the current file.
2. `lastword` plucks  the last item (Makefile name, relative to `pwd`)
3. `realpath` is built-in to `make`, and resolves to a canonical path from filesystem root
4. `dir` trims off the filename, leaving just the directory.

*Note:* The resulting `ROOT_DIR` will include the trailing path separator *(e.g. '/' on nix or '\' on Windows)*

Comment: This is the best solution I found so far. This code should be placed in the very beginning of each Makefile if you use `include` and need relative path in each of them. Yes, it does not work with spaces but none of answers using `MAKEFILE_LIST` will not work with spaces, just because `make` uses space as delimiter in `MAKEFILE_LIST`, and as a result you never know whether this space is delimiter or part of file path or file name. That makes me sad(

Comment: Note, re the above comment: instead of placing at the beginning of _each Makefile_ this could also be in the _included Makefile_ and only listed once.  Depending, I suppose, on what exactly one is doing.  But assuming multiple Makefiles all using things like `include ../../make.inc` or whatever (with varying levels of `../`), it can give `make.inc` a path to where it lives, which is presumably the base of other things.

Comment: Nice and clean. Shouldn't we care for the trailing slash at the end of the path?

Comment: @HoseinRahnama I think that at least merits a mention, I'll add it.

Answer (score 11):

I like the chosen answer, but I think it would be more helpful to actually show it working than explain it.

/tmp/makefile_path_test.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash -eu

# Create a testing dir
temp_dir=/tmp/makefile_path_test
proj_dir=$temp_dir/dir1/dir2/dir3
mkdir -p $proj_dir

# Create the Makefile in $proj_dir
# (Because of this, $proj_dir is what $(path) should evaluate to.)
cat > $proj_dir/Makefile <<'EOF'
path := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))))
cwd  := $(shell pwd)

all:
    @echo "MAKEFILE_LIST: $(MAKEFILE_LIST)"
    @echo "         path: $(path)"
    @echo "          cwd: $(cwd)"
    @echo ""
EOF

# See/debug each command
set -x

# Test using the Makefile in the current directory
cd $proj_dir
make

# Test passing a Makefile
cd $temp_dir
make -f $proj_dir/Makefile

# Cleanup
rm -rf $temp_dir
```

Output:

```
+ cd /tmp/makefile_path_test/dir1/dir2/dir3
+ make
MAKEFILE_LIST:  Makefile
         path: /private/tmp/makefile_path_test/dir1/dir2/dir3
          cwd: /tmp/makefile_path_test/dir1/dir2/dir3

+ cd /tmp/makefile_path_test
+ make -f /tmp/makefile_path_test/dir1/dir2/dir3/Makefile
MAKEFILE_LIST:  /tmp/makefile_path_test/dir1/dir2/dir3/Makefile
         path: /tmp/makefile_path_test/dir1/dir2/dir3
          cwd: /tmp/makefile_path_test

+ rm -rf /tmp/makefile_path_test
```

**NOTE:** The function `$(patsubst %/,%,[path/goes/here/])` is used to strip the trailing slash.

Answer (score 8):

I tried many of these answers, but on my AIX system with gnu make 3.80 I needed to do some things old school.

Turns out that `lastword`, `abspath` and `realpath` were not added until 3.81. :(

```
mkfile_path := $(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)),$(MAKEFILE_LIST))
mkfile_dir:=$(shell cd $(shell dirname $(mkfile_path)); pwd)
current_dir:=$(notdir $(mkfile_dir))
```

As others have said, not the most elegant as it invokes a shell twice, and it still has the spaces issues.

But as I don't have any spaces in my paths, it works for me regardless of how I started `make`:

- make -f ../wherever/makefile
- make -C ../wherever
- make -C ~/wherever
- cd ../wherever; make

All give me `wherever` for `current_dir` and the absolute path to `wherever` for `mkfile_dir`.

Comment: I, for one, have compiled gnu-make-3.82 on aix (5-6-7) without problems.

Comment: Yes, by 3.81 the needed functions for the earlier solutions were implemented.  My answer is for older systems with 3.80 or earlier.  Sadly, at work I am not allowed to add or upgrade tools to the AIX system. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is one-liner to get absolute path to your `Makefile` file using shell syntax:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
CWD := $(shell cd -P -- '$(shell dirname -- "$0")' && pwd -P)
```

And here is version without shell based on [@0xff answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18137056/55075):

```
CWD := $(abspath $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))))
```

Test it by printing it, like:

```
cwd:
        @echo $(CWD)
```

Comment: Critical Importance!  The second example above needs the := assignment operator or else some very weird and angry things can happen with complex makefiles (trust me)

Comment: First one is a repeated error and doesn't work for out-of-tree-builds.

Comment: Unfortunately, `CWD := $(shell cd -P -- '$(shell dirname -- "$0")' && pwd -P)` always returns the directory from which you executed `make` and it may differ from the directory of Makefile. Such approach would work for shell scripting but not in `make`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware this is the only answer here that works correctly with spaces:

```
space:= 
space+=

CURRENT_PATH := $(subst $(lastword $(notdir $(MAKEFILE_LIST))),,$(subst $(space),\$(space),$(shell realpath '$(strip $(MAKEFILE_LIST))')))
```

It essentially works by escaping space characters by substituting `' '` for `'\ '` which allows Make to parse it correctly, and then it removes the filename of the makefile in `MAKEFILE_LIST` by doing another substitution so you're left with the directory that makefile is in. Not exactly the most compact thing in the world but it does work.

You'll end up with something like this where all the spaces are escaped:

```
$(info CURRENT_PATH = $(CURRENT_PATH))

CURRENT_PATH = /mnt/c/Users/foobar/gDrive/P\ roje\ cts/we\ b/sitecompiler/
```

Answer (score 1):

use `{}` instead of `()`

```
cur_dir=${shell pwd}
parent_dir=${shell dirname ${shell pwd}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for your reference, as below:

The folder structure might be as:

[image]

Where there are two Makefiles, each as below;

```
sample/Makefile
test/Makefile
```

Now, let us see the content of the Makefiles.

> sample/Makefile

```
export ROOT_DIR=${PWD}

all:
    echo ${ROOT_DIR}
    $(MAKE) -C test
```

> test/Makefile

```
all:
    echo ${ROOT_DIR}
    echo "make test ends here !"
```

Now, execute the sample/Makefile, as;

```
cd sample
make
```

> OUTPUT:

```
echo /home/symphony/sample
/home/symphony/sample
make -C test
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/symphony/sample/test'
echo /home/symphony/sample
/home/symphony/sample
echo "make test ends here !"
make test ends here !
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/symphony/sample/test'
```

Explanation, would be that the parent/home directory can be stored in the environment-flag, and can be exported, so that it can be used in all the sub-directory makefiles.

Comment: This gets the current working directory, not the makefile's home directory.

Comment: These are the lines in the Makefile. Now, as the Makefile command executes, this will get the path at which the Makefile is. I understand "makefile home directory" is refering to the same, i.e. the directory-path in which Makefile is executing.

Comment: @Jesse Chisholm please revisit. I have explained with usage.

Comment: A repeated error: it doesn't work for out-of-tree-builds. Also, your gnome terminal provides a simple way to copy text: just select it. The rumor has Imgur is brankrupt.

Answer (score -1):

Solution found here : https://sourceforge.net/p/ipt-netflow/bugs-requests-patches/53/

**The solution is** : $(CURDIR)

You can use it like that :

```
CUR_DIR = $(CURDIR)

## Start :
start:
    cd $(CUR_DIR)/path_to_folder
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you add more detail to your answer? The question states that `$(CURDIR)` was already tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: WARNING, quick-googlers: This is *not* the directory, where the makefile is, but the current *working* directory (where `make` was launched in). It is, indeed, what OP really wanted, but the question title is bogus, so the question itself is inconsistent. So, this is a correct answer to an incorrect question. ;)

Comment: This is flat out wrong and a redundant wrong answer

Answer (score -2):

update 2018/03/05
finnaly I use this:

---

```
shellPath=`echo $PWD/``echo ${0%/*}`

# process absolute path
shellPath1=`echo $PWD/`
shellPath2=`echo ${0%/*}`
if [ ${shellPath2:0:1} == '/' ] ; then
    shellPath=${shellPath2}
fi
```

---

It can be executed correct in relative path or absolute path.
Executed correct invoked by crontab.
Executed correct in other shell.

show example, a.sh print self path.

```
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz /]# more /root/test/a.sh
shellPath=`echo $PWD/``echo ${0%/*}`

# process absolute path
shellPath1=`echo $PWD/`
shellPath2=`echo ${0%/*}`
if [ ${shellPath2:0:1} == '/' ] ; then
    shellPath=${shellPath2}
fi

echo $shellPath
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz /]# more /root/b.sh
shellPath=`echo $PWD/``echo ${0%/*}`

# process absolute path
shellPath1=`echo $PWD/`
shellPath2=`echo ${0%/*}`
if [ ${shellPath2:0:1} == '/' ] ; then
    shellPath=${shellPath2}
fi

$shellPath/test/a.sh
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz /]# ~/b.sh
/root/test
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz /]# /root/b.sh
/root/test
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz /]# cd ~
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz ~]# ./b.sh
/root/./test
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz ~]# test/a.sh
/root/test
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz ~]# cd test
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz test]# ./a.sh
/root/test/.
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz test]# cd /
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz /]# /root/test/a.sh
/root/test
[root@izbp1a7wyzv7b5hitowq2yz /]#
```

---

old: 
I use this:

```
MAKEFILE_PATH := $(PWD)/$({0%/*})
```

It can show correct if executed in other shell and other directory.

Comment: "It can show correct if executed if other shell and other directory" doesn't make sense in English. Can you try explaining again?

Comment: sorry for my poor english

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I see you meant IN now. Can you explain what this does before I try it? I'm not sure how to use it. Like what do you mean by "other shell"

Comment: This answer has so many wrong things it can't possibly be fixed. I suggest a simple removal.

Answer (score -3):

One line in the Makefile should be enough:

`DIR := $(notdir $(CURDIR))`