# Is it possible to specify a #include file path relative to the user's current directory when compiling?

Tags: c, gcc, path, include

I know it is possible to specify `#include` filepaths either relative to the directory the file is located in, as an absolute file path, or relative to any of the directories in the `$PATH` system variable. Is there a way to instead specify it relative to the user's current directory when the program is compiled? Let's say I have the following file structure:

```
|--dir_a/
|  |--a.c
|  |--a.h
|--dir_b/
|  |--b.c
|  |--b.h
|--makefile
```

Now let's say I want to `#include` the file `dir_a/a.h` from `dir_b/b.h`. Using the location of `dir_b/b.h`, this can be written like this:

```
#include ../dir_a/a.h
```

However, this approach has a major flaw in my opinion since it hardcodes the locations of files relative to each other, meaning that relocating a file would require updating the file path everywhere that file was included from.

Using absolute file paths would avoid this problem, but would instead hardcode the location of the project within the filesystem, which seems like bad practice.

Finally, using the `<>` tags to specify the file path isn't feasible either since I can't assume the project will be listed in the `$PATH` variable.

So what I want to do is to be able to specify the paths relative to where the user compiles from (or even better, from the location of the makefile). In the above example, this would let me use the following statement to `#include` `dir_a/a.h` from `dir_b/b.h`:

```
#include dir_a/a.h
```

This I think would be the ideal solution. It would make the `#include` statements more consistent and easier to follow, as well as avoid the drawbacks I listed above. Is it possible to do this in any way, eg. with a compiler flag or something? I'm using `gcc` as my compiler.

Comment: `$PATH` has nothing to do with it. Use `-I`.

Comment: This seems promising. How exactly would I use it to specify the project's root dir?

Comment: Use `#include "path/to/file.h"` instead of `#include <file.h>`?

Comment: Thanks. This helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consistently use `<>` includes, then the `-I` options in the makefile should be enough.  The directory layout shows only one `makefile`, in the parent directory.  That could use

```
-Idir_a -Idir_b
```

in the compiler options, and the .c files could just do

```
#include <a.h>
#include <b.h>
```

One of the problems with quoted includes is that their behavior with other compilers may differ, as noted in [What is the difference between `#include <filename>` and `#include “filename”`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) (the standard was not explicit enough).  Using a gcc extension probably does not improve that situation.

Comment: Good point about cross-compiler compatibility. I hadn't considered that. At the same time, the compiler (`gcc` in this case) is already hardcoded into the makefile. This approach also goes against the standard practice of using `<>` for system libraries and `""` for header files local to the program, which is mentioned in the top answer to the question you linked. Finally, using the `-I` flag on every directory could potentially lead to name conflicts in a situation with files where there are identically namedfiles in different directories.

Comment: The OP's example does not have the problem you suggest.  I stopped using quoted includes quite a while ago, because gcc differs from most other compilers in this area.

Comment: Ok, thought quoted includes were part of the C standard, but I guess not. How are naming conflicts caused by identically named files in different directories resolved using this answer though?

Comment: They are - but whether a quoted include will get a file in the directory containing the file which includes it (without a compiler option) is *not*.  Bracketed includes are more predictable.  Conflicts in any case are resolved by the order of `-I` options.  It is easiest to see the difference when considering nested includes - gcc looks first in the including file's directory, while other compilers may not.  Likely someone's written a page about it.

Comment: For reference - see xterm [patch #85](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_85) (1998), where quoted includes were changed to bracketed includes.

Comment: Nice find. Now how do you specify the project's root directory using the `-I` flag? The examples given just specify the subdirectories.

Comment: The usual way is `-I.`  (occasionally I use full paths with `-I` options, but usually in that case they are generated by a build-time script).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem.

The first part of the solution involves specifying the `-iquote` flag in `gcc` when compiling. From `man gcc`:

```
-iquotedir
    Add the directory dir to the head of the list of directories to be searched for header files only for the case of #include "file"; they are not searched for #include <file>, otherwise just like -I.
```

The second part of the puzzle was how to get the path to the `makefile` within the `makefile` itself. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23324703/1097658) worked for me. I'm pasting the solution here for convenience:

```
ROOT_DIR = $(shell dirname $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
```

**edit**: While this approach works, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592574/1097658) is more cross-compiler friendly, so I'm personally going to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any include file, which is not directly in your `include` path specified in your project linker settings, should have all subfolders up to it specified, like:

```
#include "first/second/third/folder/library.h"
```