# How can I use QT creator "follow symbol under cursor" feature without using qmake

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have an existing C++ project that uses a standard makefile which I have imported into QT creator 4.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. It compiles and runs fine from the build menu in creator, but in the editor some of the `#include`s are underlined in yellow (with error "No such file or directory"), and the symbols from those headers consequently fail to resolve when I use the "follow symbol under cursor" feature.

Includes such as the following appear to work fine:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "myInclude.h"
```

Whereas includes from custom libraries do not:

```
#include <some_namespace/something.h>
```

If I change the above non-functional include to:

```
#include "../../../some_library_proj/include/some_namespace/something.h"
```

then it works.

There is a file `myproject.includes` that includes the path `../some_library_proj/include/some_namespace`, but that doesn't appear to have any effect on the problem at hand.

I have searched for similar discussions online, and they usually mention editing a `.pro` file, however I believe this should not apply in my case since I'm not using qmake.

What files or environment variables do I need to change to get my imports working?

Comment: Not quite an answer to your situation, but in "Tools" => "Options" there is a C++ section. The tab "Code Model" allows you to specify additional options such as additional include paths. However AFAIK these are system-wide settings.

Answer (score 0):

Include the lower-level folders in the `myproject.includes` file as well. In this case:

`../some_library_proj/include/`

Comment: Rather than using a completely relative path, you may want to look at [How to get current relative directory of your Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136918/how-to-get-current-relative-directory-of-your-makefile) E.g. `$(mkfile_path)../some_library_proj/include/