# How to get the basename of the parent directory of a makefile in GNU make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose you want to have a makefile that shall generate one file named after the parent directory. One way to do that is to hard-code the target name but that's not very "generic", e.g.

```
TARGET := dirname.pdf

$(TARGET): $(TARGET:.pdf=.tex)
    pdflatex $(@:.pdf=.tex)
```

It would be much nicer to retrieve the directory name via make functions. There are various questions (and answers) on SA on how to retrieve the full path of a makefile (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/18137056/1905491) but not the name of the parent directory...

What's the most efficient and portable way to do that in GNU make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use the built-in [file name functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions)?

```
TARGET := $(notdir $(CURDIR))
```

I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "parent directory"; it's a bit ambiguous.  A specific example with a pathname and the result you wanted would make it easier to understand.

Comment: This seems to be even more elegant than [Vroomfondel's solution] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52784116/1905491). First I thought it would not work when using `-C` but documentation states explicitly that `CURDIR` is set after any `-C` operation has been applied and I have tested it with GNU make 4.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It depends very much on what you mean by "parent" directory. After all, make can only operate on strings and has no real notion of directories and files in terms of a datatype. You can e.g. extract the last name of a path by calling this function:

```
parent_name = $(lastword $(subst /, ,$(dir $(abspath $1))))
$(info $(call parent_name,/home/stefanct/myproject/foo.c))
```

Output:

```
myproject
```

Comment: Right, I forgot to remove the makefile's name from the path with `dir`. From there it's easy with `lastword` (cf. my [convoluted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52783387/1905491) :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If by parent directory you mean:

Makefile path:

```
/some/file/path/Makefile
```

Makefile directory:

```
/some/file/path
```

Parent directory (of Makefile)

```
/some/file
```

Then the following simple code is probably what you're looking for:

```
 MK_PATH:=$(dir $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
 MK_PARENT:=$(realpath $(MK_PATH)../)
```

Comment: I have the same understanding for OP's question. Watch out if your $(MK_PATH) variable is defined without a "/" at the end. In that case you will need to add a "/" to "MK_PARENT:=$(realpath $(MK_PATH)/../)". This got me for a while

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU make >4.0 with guile-support (output of `$(info .FEATURES)` contains `guile`) *and* the basename does not contain spaces the following solution works without any external dependencies or subprocesses:

```
MAKEFILE_PATH:=$(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
MAKEFILE_PATH_ELEMS:=$(subst /, ,$(MAKEFILE_PATH))
PARENT_DIR:=$(word $(guile (- $(words $(MAKEFILE_PATH_ELEMS)) 1)),$(MAKEFILE_PATH_ELEMS))
```

Unfortunately, guile support is not enabled by default by (all/many?) distributions and thus this requires to install a distinctive package (e.g., `make-guile` on Ubuntu) that provides guile support and replaces the ordinary `make`.