# How to edit Makefile to make it work with NetBeans remote build?

Tags: netbeans, makefile

I have Makefile like this:

```
obj-m += some_kernel_module.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

It works when I run `make` from build machine locally (when my current directory is `/home/myaccount/src/some_kernel_module/`).

However when I'm trying to compile this remotely in Netbeans I'm getting this error:

> /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-6-common/scripts/Makefile.build:44:
> /home/myaccount/Makefile: No such file or directory

I guess that's because I have `M=$(PWD)` in my Makefile, and Netbeans Build Host current directory is my home (`/home/myaccount`) instead of project directory `/home/myaccount/src/some_kernel_module/`).

**How can I fix that?**

---

I have entered path manually and it works locally and remotely:

```
obj-m += some_kernel_module.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=/home/myaccount/src/some_kernel_module/ modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=/home/myaccount/src/some_kernel_module/ clean
```

But this is not an answer. I don't want this absolute path in my Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer here:

[How to get current relative directory of your Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136918/how-to-get-current-relative-directory-of-your-makefile)

I had to get and store makefile directory like this:

```
THIS_DIR := $(dir $(abspath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
```

And use it instead of `PWD` (complete Makefile):

```
obj-m += some_kernel_module.o
THIS_DIR := $(dir $(abspath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(THIS_DIR) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(THIS_DIR) clean
```

*Edit: As https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist suggested in comments below I changed `make` to `$(MAKE)`.*

Comment: You should always use `$(MAKE)` when invoking sub-makes, never `make`.

Comment: @MadScientist Looks like I have read wrong kernel driver tutorial... Thanks for suggestion. Is that because we don't want to run multiple processes or something like that?

Comment: Is what?  Using `$(MAKE)`?  It's so that (a) if you run `gmake` (or whatever) instead of `make` that your sub-makes are also `gmake`, (b) all appropriate command line flags and variable overrides are passed to sub-makes, and (c) parallel builds are set up properly for sub-makes.