# Included Makefile's parent directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to describe each submake's dependencies in a file that a top-level `Makefile` can include.  This is to allows for a recursive make setup (with all of the power of instanced variables and relative pathing) but with all dependencies described in a top-level make to increase compile speed and parallelism.

For instance, let's assume we have a directory tree that looks like this:

```
project/
|-- lib1
|   |-- Makefile
|   `-- Makefile.reg
|-- lib2
|   |-- Makefile
|   `-- Makefile.reg
|-- Makefile
`-- Makefile.reg
```

The file for `project/lib1/Makefile.reg` file may look like this:

```
REG := lib1
include ../Makefile.reg
```

The file for `project/lib2/Makefile.reg` file may look like this:

```
REG := lib2
DEP := lib1
include ../Makefile.reg
```

The file `project/Makefile.reg` will look like this:

```
$(REG)_DIR = ????
$(REG): $(DEP)
  $(MAKE) -C $($@_DIR)
```

And finally, the top-level `project/Makefile` would look like this:

```
include $(shell find . -name "Makefile.reg")
```

Now, the top-level `Makefile` has all of the dependency information for every target and can intelligently call recursive make and utilize full parallelism while keeping the dependency tree intact.

The issue is that I'm not sure how to let `project/Makefile.reg` know what the current submake's `Makefile.reg`'s path is.  `make` will always be called from the top-level directory, so `$(shell  pwd)` will always report `project/`.  One solution would be to include the line from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322936/common-gnu-makefile-directory-path) SO answer, however I would like each `Makefile.reg` to only specify a target and an optional dependency list.

Is there a way to include the directory path discovery in the common `project/Makefile.reg` rather than putting a new line in every single submake `Makefile.reg`?  In other words, can an included makefile deduce the parent makefile's directory?  I see potential in some different parsing of the `MAKEFILE_LIST` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the snippet of documentation included in the answer on your linked ticket indicates. The value of `MAKEFILE_LIST` is updated as make goes. The latest entry in the list is the current makefile which makes the penultimate entry in the list the most recently included makefile before that. If you are willing to assert that the main `project/Makefile.reg` will only ever be included from a sub-directory makefile then it could simply examine that entry in `MAKEFILE_LIST`.

Alternatively you could simply define a [canned recipe](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) in the main `Makefile` and call it in each project makefile to define the appropriate targets.

Unfortunately make does make getting the penultimate entry a little more difficult than is pleasant. But the following should work:

```
FOO=a b c d e f g
BAR=h i j k l m n
BAZ=o p q r s t u
QUX=v w x y z 1 2

penultimateword = $(wordlist $(words $1),$(words $1), x $1)

REG=FOO
$(REG)_DIR= $(call penultimateword,$($(REG)))
$(info REG_DIR=$($(REG)_DIR))

REG=BAR
$(REG)_DIR= $(call penultimateword,$($(REG)))
$(info REG_DIR=$($(REG)_DIR))

REG=BAZ
$(REG)_DIR= $(call penultimateword,$($(REG)))
$(info REG_DIR=$($(REG)_DIR))

REG=QUX
$(REG)_DIR= $(call penultimateword,$($(REG)))
$(info REG_DIR=$($(REG)_DIR))

all: ;
```

Inspiration for the above came from the `chop` function from the fantastic [GMSL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmsl/).

Comment: The question basically boils down to how to get the `last-1` entry from MAKEFILE_LIST rather than just the last entry.

Comment: @Aggieboy I realized you may not have seen that I edited my answer to include a way to get the word you needed. If so, sorry about that.

Comment: Ahh interesting!  I was doing `reverse = $(if $(1),$(call reverse,$(wordlist 2,$(words $(1)),$(1)))) $(firstword $(1))` and then `$(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(word 2,$(call reverse,$(MAKEFILE_LIST)))))`, but your solution may be far quicker.  Let me try it before accepting.