# Get word before the last word inside GNU makefile

Tags: makefile

I need to extract the word before the last from `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)`.

So far I could not come up with anything better than this kind of monstrosity:

```
LIST := a b c

LAST_WORD_INDEX = $(words $(LIST))
BEFORE_LAST := $(word $(shell echo $(LAST_WORD_INDEX) - 1 | bc),$(LIST))
$(info word before last is $(BEFORE_LAST))
```

When I run it:

```
word before last is b
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

The result is correct, but is there more elegant and sane way to achieve the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Included Makefile's parent directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960054/included-makefiles-parent-directory)

Comment: Not a duplicate of the exact goal but my answer there has what you need (and I actually talk about `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)` in my answer.

Comment: @EtanReisner thank you for the GMSL pointer

Comment: You could use `$(lastword $(filter-out $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)), $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))`.

Comment: @Beta -- Sorry, commenting on this a bit late -- if the last two entries in the list were identical, i.e. `a b c c`, then the `filter-out` would wipe out both `c`'s, and would incorrectly return `b`...

Comment: @HardcoreHenry: You're right, good catch.

Answer (score 5):

`$(words ${LIST})` will give you the index of the *last-but-one* word if you prepend an element to *LIST*.

```
BEFORE_LAST := $(word $(words ${LIST}),1st ${LIST})
```

Notice that `1st` in there.

Comment: You put `$(words ${LIST})` an extra time in there.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Did you try it? That is correct. If _LIST_ has 4 words, we make it a 5 word list and take the 4th word `$(word 4,4,1st a b c d)`. Neat huh?

Comment: @HardcoreHenry No, I am wrong of course, I'm not using `$(wordlist)`. And _make_ is wrong too, nice one!. Looks like `$(word 4, …args…, list)` "works." It takes the word from the list it finds in its _last_ argument. Oh well.

Comment: So, after a little investigation, it looks like this would fail if there were exactly two entries in the list.   Because `word` is a built-in that expects exactly two parameters, the second comma does not act as a parameter delimiter -- so  `$(info word 1: $(word 1,1,a b c d))`, `1,a` is considered the first word.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Yes, again you are right about `$(word)` ignoring the second comma. However, my original formulation with the two calls to `$(words)` still works, even when `${LIST}` has zero or one word. The augmented list merely has something like `1,1st` as its new first item. I have edited the text. Thank you for noticing!

Comment: What's `,1st` ?

Comment: @CervEd See the first paragraph! `1st ${LIST}` extends the length of _$LIST_ by one. A standard trick in _make_ where we have no arithmetic macros.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using [GMSL](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) library, which makes things quite a bit more coherent:

```
include gmsl-1.1.6/gmsl

$(lastword $(call chop,$(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
```