# Makefile: extract pattern from a full path string

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching

In a Makefile, I can get the full path string by `$(CURDIR)`. The result is like `/home/jones/prj/platform/Application_UBUNTU/build_os`. How do I extract the `UBUNTU` from the string?

I use subst to replace '/' as space.

`DIR = $(subst /, " ", $(CURDIR))`

I get result as `home jones prj platform Application_UBUNTU build_os`.

Then I try to use filter command but I cannot use % or wildcard to match `Application_UBUNTU` out. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `penultimateword` macro from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24960885/258523).

```
penultimateword = $(wordlist $(words $1),$(words $1), x $1)

BUILD_OS=$(call penultimateword,$(subst /, ,$(CURDIR)))
BUILD_OS=$(subst _, ,$(BUILD_OS))
BUILD_OS=$(word 2,$(BUILD_OS))
```

This is obviously sensitive to extra underscores in the path/etc.

Comment: It's amazing and works well. However, I don't know how it works. If I want to extract the second word with underscore '_', in my example, it's `os` from the `build_os`, where should I modify? Thanks.

Comment: I got it. I can use the `lastword` macro to get `build_os` part. `lastword = $(word $(words $1), $1)`